# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "company"

Tags: configuration, symfony

The error is a consequence of this configuration and i can't find out where i'm wrong.

This is the bundle

```
<?php
namespace Company;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class CompanyBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```

This is the configuration

```
<?php
// In src/Company/DependencyInjection
namespace Company\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface {

    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();

        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('company');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('login')
                    ->children()
                        ->integerNode('login_attempts')->defaultValue(0)->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end() // login
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Then my Extension

```
<?php
// In src/Company/DependencyInjection

namespace Company\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class CompanyExtension extends Extension{

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container){ 

        $configuration = new Configuration();

        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
                $container,
                new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
                );

        $loader->load('config.yaml');

    }
}
```

At least my config file

```
# In src/Company/Resources/config/config.yaml
company:
    login:
        login_attempts: 3
```

The error is

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 431:
>   There is no extension able to load the configuration for "company" (in /home/wwwcompany/company/src/Company/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/config.yaml). Looked for namespace "company", found none

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add CompanyBundle to AppKernel.php?  Also, CowbellExtension needs to be CompanyExtension unless you override in CompanyBundle.

Comment: See if this helps. [Setting configurations in dependency injection extension file](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/nx69/setting-configurations-in-dependency-injection-extension-file)

Comment: @Cerad sorry the name of extension is correct. In my post was a mistake. Also added the bundle to kernel.

Comment: So dies it work?  If not add a die statement to your extension and confirm it is getting called.  I suspect you are making significant edits to your posted question which can make things challenging.

Comment: @Cerad Nope it doesn't work. I just made that mistake while editing the post first time.